# go lint tools range closure detection

Tags: go, static-analysis, lint, linter

Been trying to use [gonnel](https://github.com/afdalwahyu/gonnel) for some tunnels. Tried to open 2 tunnels, and then when they got closed, I noticed that the log package is saying that is trying to close the same tunnel twice. From looking at the code, it seems that (one of) the problems is this:
[image]

I thought I would take advantage of staticcheck, golangci-lint or even go vet to have it highlight this problem, so that I can be more confident on a fix. However, when I run the tools, I get this output:

golangci-lint:
[image]

go vet:

[image]

staticcheck:

[image]

Also tried running go vet with -loopclosure, but I still don't get any output. Shouldn't one of the tools say that the go func needs the iterator variable passed as param? If it helps, I'm running go 1.14.3 darwin/amd64, and also tried importing the code in goland, but I didn't get an inspection warning for that piece of code. I am getting a feeling that I might be doing something wrong, could you spot what it is?

Thanks!

Comment: Ignoring the linter warnings, one issue could be that `c.Tunnel` contains duplicates. I noticed that `AddTunnel` doesn't check for duplicate insertions. If there are duplicates, there could be a race on `t.IsCreated`. Since `CloseTunnel` and `DisconnectAll` don't use `t.IsCreated` in a thread-safe way, it's possible that two of the closure goroutines can be spawned for the same tunnel if it's in `c.Tunnel` twice.

Comment: What version of Go (and linters) are you using? The warning was not in some older ones.

Comment: using `go 1.14.3`, `staticcheck 2020.1.4`, and `golangci-lint has version 1.27.0 built from fb74c2e on 2020-05-13T18:45:55Z`

Comment: `Shouldn't one of the tools say that the go func needs the iterator variable passed as param?` this is opinion based and you should talk about that with the lib authors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, correct. This problem is very common among Gophers ([What happens with closures running as goroutines?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines))!

Go vet's issues:

1. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21412
2. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16520

So, it seems you don't see an output with go vet because the goroutine in within an `if` block. Could you try doing it without the `if` block? I think your issue is more relevant [Issue 21412](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21412)

---

Similarly for [golangci/govet](https://github.com/golangci/govet/blob/master/rangeloop.go):

Quoting from the `golangci/govet/rangeloop.go`'s code:

```
This file contains the code to check range loop variables bound inside function
literals that are deferred or launched in new goroutines. We only check
instances where the defer or go statement is the last statement in the loop
body, as otherwise, we would need whole-program analysis.
```

---

Also, my suggestion would be to check if tunnels are open and then only close it. It might happen that you duplicate entries, so then again there's a possibility of some issue. And do fix the closure running as a goroutine error, first.

So, here's an example where the `if` block is a differentiator on how `go vet` works.

- With `if` block, `go vet` returns nothing

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "sync"
)

func main() {
        fruits := []string{"orange", "apple"}
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        for _, fruit := range fruits {
                if true {
                        wg.Add(1)
                        go func() {
                                fmt.Println(fruit)
                                wg.Done()
                        }()
                }
        }
        wg.Wait()
}
```

- Without `if` block, `go vet` returns `loop variable fruit captured by func literal`

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "sync"
)

func main() {
        fruits := []string{"orange", "apple"}
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        for _, fruit := range fruits {
                wg.Add(1)
                go func() {
                        fmt.Println(fruit)
                        wg.Done()
                }()
        }
        wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: @geo If this answer helped you, could you please accept it? Thanks!

Comment: hey @shmsr , sorry, didn't get a chance to try it! Will try it in the morning and then accept, thanks!